# How to write one method instead of many to obtain user input and assign values to the correct variables?

Tags: c#

I am writing a console app, and need to get some values from the user. I've done the following:

```
public static void getAge()
{
    Console.Write("Age: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        int.TryParse(input, out Age);
}
```

I have 3 other identical methods for getting and assigning `Height`, `Weight` and `Width`. It seems better to have just one method for all of them, not 4 identical ones. I thought about putting strings with names of variables in an array, and looping through them. This works for the third line of code:

```
string[] params = new string[] {"Age", "Height", ...}

foreach (var p in params)
{
    Console.Write($"{p}: ");
    ...
}
```

But how is it possible to assign the output to the correct variable in the last line?

```
int.TryParse(input, out Age);
```

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing the input prompts in an array, the values that the user inputs are also going to be stored in an array.

```
int[] inputs = new int[params.Length];
```

Instead of using a foreach loop, you should use a for loop, so that you can loop through both arrays at the same time.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < inputs.Length ; i++) {
    Console.Write(params[i]);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) {
        int.TryParse(input, out inputs[i]); // "magic" is here
    }
}
```

Now, `input[0]` is the age, `input[1]` is the height etc.

Answer (score 1):

I like the array and other examples, but there is also something simple like this using a `return`, I've added retry validation for fun

```
public static int GetStuff(string title)
{
   var value = 0;
   Console.WriteLine($"{title}: ");
   while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
      Console.WriteLine($"You had one job! {title}: ");
   return value;
}
```

**Usage**

```
AgeProperty = GetStuff("Age"e);
WidthVariable = GetStuff("Width");
SomeMethod(GetStuff("Height"));
```

if you wanted to get even more fancy, you could write a generic version that tries to convert using `Convert.ChangeType` (though it will be limited to simple types).

```
public static T GetStuff<T>(string title)
{
   T result = default;

   Console.Write($"{title}: ");

   while (Local(Console.ReadLine()))
      Console.WriteLine($"You had one job, {title}: ");

   return result;

   bool Local(string value)
   {
      try
      {
         result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));

         return true;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          // didnt work
      }

      return false;

   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static int Age;
public static decimal Height;

...

Age = GetStuff<int>("Age");
Height = GetStuff<decimal>("Height");
```

Comment: Why are you using action instead of return?

Comment: @David no reason really, just decided to do it that way when i was returning success :) ill make a note

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public static T Input<T>(string? display = default)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(display))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{display}: ");
    }
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));
}
```

```cs
var age = Input<int>("Age");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach, but instead of writing separate methods for each input (like Name, Age, Height, etc), another option is to create helper methods that takes in a string used to prompt the user for input, and then return a strongly typed value back to the caller.

For strings it's quite simple:

```
private static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But for other types, like a number or a date, we need to validate that the user entered in a string that can be converted. For these types of methods, I use a `do/while` loop, whose condition is the result of a `TryParse` method (which return a `bool` indicating whether or not a string was successfully converted to the type, and which take an `out` parameter of that type that gets set to the converted value).

I also added an optional "validator" argument, which allows the caller to specify some additional constraints in the form of a method that takes in an argument of the specified type and returns a bool indicating whether or not the argument is valid (like if the age entered must be greater than 16 and less than 100, for example). I used an inline lambda expression in the example at the bottom, but you could pass the name of a method as well.

Here's one for getting an integer from the user:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
             !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

private static void ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(int cursorTop, string message)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

Now, with methods like these, we can do this:

```
string userName = GetStringFromUser("Enter your name: ");
int userAge = GetIntFromUser("How old are you (16-100): ", x => x >= 16 && x <= 10);
```

Comment: I like the validator, plus one

Answer (score -2):

There are a multitude of ways you could structure this, for example if you use a dictionary you can load it with any number of keys, even at run time and then request their values

Here's a quick inline form:

```
//declare a dictionary pre initialized with all the properties we will ask for
var d = new Dictionary<string, int> {
  ["Age"] = 0, ["weight"] = 0, ["height"] = 0, ["width"] = 0
};

//for each of the keys (toarray makes a new collection so we are not enumerating the collection we are modifying)
foreach(var key in d.Keys.ToArray()){
  //uses string interpolation to compose a string using the key name (age, height etc)
  Console.WriteLine($"enter {key}:");
  int val = 0; //to store the value we parse

  //while the user enters bad input and we can't parse it
  while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val)){
    Console.WriteLine($"need an integer input for {key}:" );
  }
  //store the parsed value in the dictionary against the current key
  d[key] = val;
}

//example of use
Console.WriteLine($"Your BMI is {10000.0 * d["weight"] / d["height"] / d["height"]}");
```

At the end of it you have a dictionary populated with all the entered values, and you can reference them by string names rather than variable names in code

Now let's expand things so that these become named variables in a dedicated class. We'll fill the dictionary in the same way, but we can access them by name:

```
class Person{

  private Dictionary<string, int> _d = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    ["age"] = 0, ["weight"] = 0, ["height"] = 0, ["width"] = 0
  };

  public int Age { get { return _d["age"]; } set { _d["age"] = value; } }

  public int Weight { get { return _d["weight"]; } set { _d["weight"] = value; } }

  public int Height { get { return _d["height"]; } set { _d["height"] = value; } }

  public int Width { get { return _d["width"]; } set { _d["width"] = value; } }


  //a method that requests all properties from the user
  public void AskAll(){

    foreach(var key in _d.Keys.ToArray()){
      Console.WriteLine($"enter {key}:");
      int val = 0; 

      while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val)){
        Console.WriteLine($"need an integer input for {key}:" );
      }
     _d[key] = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have a class for representing your person, and their properties, and you can get values for all the properties using a loop. You might use it like this:

```
class Program{
  static void Main(string[] args){
    Person p = new Person();

    p.AskAll();

    //assuming height in cm, weight in kg
    Console.WriteLine($"Your BMI is {10000.0 * p.Weight / p.Height / p.Height}");

  }
}
```

If you want to break that AskAll() method out more, into a method that takes a question string and returns the answer:

```
public void AskAll(){
    foreach(var key in _d.Keys.ToArray()){
      _d[key] = AskFor(key);
    }
}

public int AskFor(string what)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"enter {what}:");

    int val = 0; 
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out val)){
        Console.WriteLine($"need an integer input for {what}:" );
    }
    return val;
}
```

There's a lot of newer c# syntax  in this; if you haven't come across bits of it before:

```
//string interpolation
$"need an integer input for {what}:"

//classic format equivalent
string.Format("need an integer input for {0}:", what);


//create and init a dictionary:
private Dictionary<string, int> _d = new Dictionary<string, int> {
    ["age"] = 0, ["weight"] = 0, ["height"] = 0, ["width"] = 0
};

//classic equivalent
private Dictionary<string, int> _d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
_d["age"] = 0;
_d["weight"] = 0;
_d["height"] = 0;
_d["width"] = 0;
```

All this said, if you're learning c# / in an academic context and you haven't been introduced to Dictionary, or string interpolation, then you should probably go with the answer that uses a pair of arrays. This question has certainly garnered some trick/neat answers with very advanced concepts but if the aim of the exercise is to cement and demonstrate what you've learnt so far in lessons, handing in something too advanced would be detrimental and could even trigger accusations of plagiarism. Be sure you I'll understand everything you hand in :)

Comment: your answer make no sense